# How to read Data that include space

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a txt file that include information as follow:

"

Jack

Jim

Bill's Father

"

I have no problem reading the all the data with ifstream using something like:

ifstream myReadFile;
myReadFile.open(mFilePath);

myReadFile >>a>>b>>c;

But I find that the last one only has "Bill's" without "Father" because they are separated with space.
So I wondering if there is a way to include space in one datum and separate them only with \t or endl (tab or new line)
Thank you!!

Comment: Use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read entire lines at a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `getline`:

```
myReadFile.getline(a,sizeof(a));
```

This will read  a maximum of `sizeof(a)` characters from the stream until the end of the line.

With `ifstream::get` you can specify the delimiter you want.

```
myReadFile.get(a, sizeof(a), '\t');
```

This will read a maximum of `sizeof(a)` characters from the stream until it finds a '\t'.